# will too many inductors in DC power distribution cause instability?

Tags: filter, dc-dc-converter, inductor

I'm designing a circuit with different blocks, I used LC filters to isolate power in different blocks. this is how it looks:[image]
pin+ and pin- are connected to a 24VDC supply, possibly from long wires in a noisy environment. a TVS diode is placed in parallel for protection in another sheet. U22 is a switching regulator (LM2576) with fixed 5VDC output. U22 is a 3.3VDC linear regulator (TPS796). I remember from a control course in university that each stage move phase margin closer and when it reach a certain value which makes the system unstable. most of the current drawn is from 5VDCl other blocks don't use more than 100mA. I searched a bit and didn't find anything particular about this problem but then again I didn't find any circuit with this much inductors for DC filtering. pointing out anything else that I might not have considered is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure I did answer something similar in the past but can't find it now. Whenever you have a voltage source and a voltage load, choose your CLC so that the energy in the L for the maximum step in current is much less than the energy in your C's at the max allowed voltage ripple. Current swing is 100 % but you may only tolerate 5 % voltage ripple. Your 3V3DCA will not be happy since you have created an CL and not CLC, so it's not voltge stiff. Also, can you clarify your question down to one particular at the end?

Comment: Bypassed on another sheet how? To what ground? Anyway, draw each circuit in LTspice, apply a current step and watch the rining result. Do a hand calculation and you will see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I changed the picture. what I got from your comment is: I should calculate maximum and minimum current passing from each inductor and this energy difference in inductor's energy should be much less than the energy stored in the capacitors. so I should choose Cs and Ls with this criteria. am I right?

Comment: While there may be no load steps in your system at all and everything is constant current, but this is unlikely and since you are asking I assume not. Please calculate for example 100 mA in 10 uH for your 3.3 V, how much energy is stored there? How much of a deltaV will that cause over your 100 nF?

Comment: 544 nJ energy is stored in 3.3 V 100 nF. and 100mA step in current will cause 50 nJ energy difference in 10uH inductor and since there is another one in ground line, it would be 100 nJ. this 100nJ will cause 1.4 V voltage drop on 100nF capacitor which is not good. but there is also a 1uF there which reduce this transient voltage drop to 0.44V. which will probably cause no problem. thank you. I'm gonna repeat this analysis on other parts as well.

Comment: Aim for <5 % deltaV. Adjust currents to maximum expected for each rail.

Comment: Instability? No. But I would return L8 (and possibly L10) to C56 or even D36 so they connect to the clean regulated supply, and you don't pass on logic switching noise (admittedly, attenuated) to your sensors.